# google translate api in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, google-translate, google-translation-api

I am developing a website in angularjs and i want to show it in multiple languages. Can I use google translate api for this? If yes, then what is best to implement google translate api in angularjs and if not, what is the alternate option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theoretically, you could. But actually, you shouldn't.
Even if Google Translate is the most advanced translation service on the web, it is still/ not yet able to translate complex sentences etc. gracefully. My personal suggestion for you would be the following:

**1st:** Find a (close to) native speaker in every language you want to serve your website

**2nd:** Checkout the following article on scotch.io: https://scotch.io/tutorials/internationalization-of-angularjs-applications

**3rd:** Recheck with the official angular i18n docs: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/i18n

Best,
D

Comment: Thanx for your ans Deniz. I did it using angular-translate.

Comment: This doesn't work for user generated content. Best is a hybrid - use angular gettext or angular translate for the system text and google translate api for user-generated content.